# PythonAnywhere Django Import error for Requests despite it being listed

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

On PythonAnywhere's website they say they have requests as part of their library and it gave no error in the editor on the site but during execution it gave this :
Python Version:     3.4
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:

No module named 'requests'

However it clearly states that they have it, what is the problem ?
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/#a_python34

Comment: run pip install requests in pythonanywhere venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to enter the virtual environment.
Using <kbd>lsvirtualenv</kbd> to find the virtualenv you're using then simply use the <kbd>workon env-name</kbd> to get into that virtualenv.
Once there <kbd>pip3 install requests</kbd> and you're good to go!

The problem is essentially that when using the virtualenv you have to downaload all the packages you want manually. The 'batteries included' list is for non virtualenv usage only so it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Yup, that's how virtualenvs work -- they give you a separate Python environment that's isolated by default from whatever the system has installed.  You can change that by creating it with the `--system-site-packages` flag, which gives you a virtualenv with all of the system packages visible.  That can lead to clashes between incompatible versions, though, so it's not normally a good idea.