# install bs4 in pythonanywhere server

Tags: python, django, python-requests, pythonanywhere, beautifulsoup

I tried to install requests and beautiful soup module (bs4) in pythonanywhere server by this command:

```
pip3 install requests
```

but it got and error said: requirement already satisfied... and got an address to dist-package directory. I found requests package there but when I run my app and open my django website It gives an error said: `no module named requests`. on the other hand when I try to install bs4 using this command:

```
pip3 install bs4
```

It gives permission denied error. what should I do? how can I install a python package in pythonanywhere server.

---

I solved the error for bs4 by [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) article. but still when open the website it gives the error 'No module named requests'. when I try to install it on pythonanywhere server it gives a message that requests is installed. so what should I do for this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716462/pythonanywhere-django-import-error-for-requests-despite-it-being-listed) answer that our problem is the same, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: By the way, the package name is `beautifulsoup4`, not `bs4`.

Comment: bs4 is available for py3 with name bs4 @alecxe

Comment: @ArpitSolanki ah, yeah, they eventually created a dummy package for this exact name confusion problem https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4. Thanks, good point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--user` flag, or use a virtualenv. See the PythonAnywhere [help pages](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/).

To check what packages are already installed on PythonAnywhere go [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/).

If you are having trouble with stuff being installed but not being able to import them, make sure you have pip installed them to the right python version (eg: pip3.5 install for python3.5), or if you have installed into a virtualenv, that you have activated/you are using that virtualenv when running the code.

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnyWhere does not allow sudo access to the users so you can't install anything directly on the system. If you want to install something then you have to use a virtual environment then you can install anything in it. More information about creating a virtual env can be found [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango/)